# How to write conditional within html element in blazor?

Tags: conditional-statements, blazor

```
@if (unit.unitNum != null)
 {
      <div>@unit.unitNum - @unit.type</div>
 }
```

> Is there a way to right conditional within div element?
> I have to write conditional for unit.type too so it will be many ifs.

Comment: There is not enough information here - as it stands it seems all you need is another condition in your existing if. Or maybe you just want to use the `?` operator - `@unit?.unitNum - @unit?.type` ?  It's hard to know what you are asking for.

Comment: You haven't described what you want well enough for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: @unit?.unitNum - @unit?.type  This is a good idea but how can I have else{} if unit.unitNum and unit.type were null?

Comment: Can structs can be `null` or is it a string?? or do you mean `default`? `unit?` is testing for (unit is null)

Comment: If I make the question clearer I can say that I want to remove @if (unit.unitNum != null){} and but I want to have conditional like this: @unit?.unitNum - @unit?.type as Magoo has mentioned above. now how can I have else {} within div element?

Comment: unit.unitNum is nullable so when that is null I get error because that is not set to an instance. therfore I need to have conditional. unit.unitNum is retrieved data from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can write a conditional within a div element.

```
<div>
    @if(unit.unitNum != null)
    {
        @unit.unitNum - @unit.type
    }
    else {
        @* just do whatever you want here or don't write an else clause *@
    }
</div>
```

Note that you can also use String interpolation

```
<div>
    @if(unit.unitNum != null)
    {
        @($"{unit.unitNum} - {@unit.type}")
    }
</div>
```

You could even simplify this a bit more. Also since you didn't specify this, the type of `unit.unitNum` doesn't really matter here, e.g. it could be an `int`, or a `string`.

```
<div>
    @($"{(unit.unitNum != null ? unit.unitNum : "no number found")} - {@unit.type}")
</div>
```

Comment: great pleasure to help :)